# Generate uniqueidentifier from different values

Tags: sql-server, aggregation, uniqueidentifier

I have this output:

| valueRulesContact | valueRuleEmail |
| --- | --- |
| 3538763040maire | mcmkillarney |
| 00353876813040maire | mcmkillarney |
| 19702229029lori | loripivonkacomlori |
| 00353876813040maire | mmurph630763 |
| 00353876813040maire | mcmkillarney |
| 119702229029lori | loripivonkacomlori |
| 00353876813040maire | mmurph630763 |
| 00353876813040maire | mckillarney |
| 119702229029lori | manorscomlori |

I need to generate the same GUID with combination between valueRuleContact and valueRuleEmail.

I need the same GUID because valueRuleContact and valueRuleEmail have common values between the rows.

For Example:

valueRuleContact: 19702229029lori + valueRuleEmail:loripivonkacomlori

valueRuleContact: 119702229029lori + valueRuleEmail:loripivonkacomlori

Have the same valueRuleEmail from the top

valueRuleContact: 119702229029lori + valueRuleEmail:manorscomlori

Have the same valueRuleContact from the top

How can I do it in SQL Server?

I pretend this output...

| valueRulesContact | valueRuleEmail | GUID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3538763040maire | mcmkillarney | UNIQUE1 |
| 00353876813040maire | mcmkillarney | UNIQUE1 |
| 19702229029lori | loripivonkacomlori | UNIQUE2 |
| 00353876813040maire | mmurph630763 | UNIQUE1 |
| 00353876813040maire | mcmkillarney | UNIQUE1 |
| 119702229029lori | loripivonkacomlori | UNIQUE2 |
| 00353876813040maire | mmurph630763 | UNIQUE1 |
| 00353876813040maire | mckillarney | UNIQUE1 |
| 119702229029lori | manorscomlori | UNIQUE2 |

Thanks

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: the same uniqueidentifier for those values. the GUID column value is a unique identifier which has to be the same...

Comment: Not a GUID ... but this is an approach to create UNIQUE code base on a string.   https://dbfiddle.uk/tsv_ojW8

Comment: Sorry, I edited with more information about my problem. As needed to be de same code between valuRuleEmail and valueRuleContact

Answer (score 1):

A SQL Server UNIQUEIDENTIFIER does not have to follow the actual rules for a GUID, so you are free to cast any 128bit binary value to UNIQUEIDENTIFER.  So simply use any 128bit hash function to generate the value.

So

```
create or alter function HashToUniqueidentifier(@a varchar(2000), @b varchar(2000) )
returns uniqueidentifier
as
begin
  return cast( hashbytes('MD5',concat(@a,'|',@b)) as uniqueidentifier )
end

go 

select dbo.ToUniqueidentifier('3538763040maire','mcmkillarney')
```

Comment: An inline table valued function might be wiser, scalars are really slow.

Comment: I need the same guid between the rows. for example:

select dbo.ToUniqueidentifier('119702229029lori','manorscomlori') a
, dbo.ToUniqueidentifier('119702229029lori','loripivonkacomlori') b
, dbo.ToUniqueidentifier('19702229029lori','loripivonkacomlori') c;

Comment: Please clarify on your question why those would generate the same guid.

Comment: I need the same GUID because valueRuleContact and valueRuleEmail have common values between the rows. I put more information in detail.